# Are there options for rails bypassing rails asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In a project using, javascript with Rails4 as API engine, I encountered the following problem, that of bypassing the rails asset pipeline. Using the existing 
rails4 asset pipeline was cumbersome as in the project we were using only javascript, front end with rails4 backend for API, and json, jsonp. Is there any tools/gems that use macros, or even Java style: "import" statements to integrate with Rails4, so as to bypass the rails4 asset pipeline. If there is any tool 
that uses Java style imports. or C/C++ style "#include", this would make code more maintainable, and modular as javascript assets could be modularized thereby.  and thereby change management easier, is there anything out there 
that does this?

Comment: You could remove the "require tree" from the javascript/stylesheet file and add them manually.

Comment: actually, for large projects would this make things more effcient, like have load balancing, as the existing asset pipeline, impacts the performance.

Comment: How does asset pipeline impacts performance? Normally you precompile your assets, serve the static files and the browser caches them until they change, you could even plug in a CDN like Cloudfront in front. I'm not sure what load balancing you are refererrng to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off Rails 4 asset pipeline, use

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

in your `config/application.rb` file.

Of course, by doing that you will have to rely on an alternative asset bundling solution.

A couple of options are [Grunt](http://blog.bugsnag.com/replacing-the-rails-asset-pipeline-with-gulp) or [Webpack](https://forum.shakacode.com/t/using-webpack-with-rails/199).

Comment: any out there, that are more efficient, than the existing asset pipeline, in terms of load balancing, etc?

Comment: any preferred one over the other?

Comment: You can do your reading and make the decision yourself based on your specific constraints.